# Django matching error with choices field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

**urls.py**

```
path('preferences/<action>/<category>/', views.preferences),
```

**HTML form**

```
            <form method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% for field in location_form %}
                    {{ field.label_tag }}<br>
                    {{ field }}
                    {% for error in field.errors %}
                        <p style="color: red">{{ error }}</p>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}
                <button type="submit" formaction="/wheelwatch/preferences/save/location/">Save</button>
                <button type="submit" formaction="/wheelwatch/preferences/delete/location/">Delete</button>
            </form>
```

**views.py**

```
    elif action == 'delete':

        if category == 'location':
            # match form data to CLLocation's location field
            location_url = request.POST['location']
            location_list = CLLocation._meta.get_field('location').choices

            for location in location_list:

                if location[0] == location_url:
                    CLLocation.objects.get(location=location[1], user__username=request.user).delete()
```

I am receiving a "matching query does not exist error." I know there is an object in the database with a matching "user" and "location" field, but I can't properly access and delete it!

**models.py**

```
class CLLocation(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location_choices = (
        ('https://auburn.craigslist.org/', 'AL - auburn'),
        ...
    location = MultiSelectField(choices=location_choices)
```

Comment: If the ORM tells you there's no object matching your query, then there's no record in the database matching your query, whatever you might believe.

Comment: There are objects in the database. The ORM is only doing what it is told. I am trying to change my code to access the objects in the database, but there is evidently an error.

Comment: I'm not saying there's no record in your database but that none of them matches your query. Hint: you can check the sql issued by the orm : `qs = YourModel.objects.filter(your_query_here); print(qs.query)`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your syntax for deleting.

You are mixing up two different solutions: Get the instance, then delete or delete directly. Try one of these:

```
instance = CLLocation.objects.get(location=location[1], user__username=request.user)
instance.delete()
```

or

```
CLLocation.objects.filter(location=location[1], user__username=request.user).delete()
```

See [django help here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#deleting-objects)

Comment: The first solution returns the same error.

The second solution does not return an error, but it does not actually appear to delete the object. The view also contains the list of locations, and they are not actually getting deleted!

Comment: I might be wrong again, but have you tried: CLLocation.objects.filter(location=location[1], user=request.user).delete()? 
My experience with 'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL' is very little.

Comment: I tested that out, and it did not return an error. Unfortunately, the object is still in the database!

Answer (score 0):

just make changes in your delete query as follows:

```
CLLocation.objects.get(location=location[1], user=request.user).delete()
```

as user is itself a foreign key of AuthUser, so u just need to provide authuser object as a parameter.

Comment: I tried that. The page does not return an error, but the object is still in the database.